# Angular 2, installing library from Github repository

Tags: angular, typescript, github, npm

I'm learning how to create an Angular 2 library based on a project created with Angular-CLI. I'm going by these examples [ng-demo-lib](https://github.com/nsmolenskii/ng-demo-lib) and [ng-demo-app](https://github.com/nsmolenskii/ng-demo-app) by Nikita Smolenskii.

The library dependency is listed like this in package.json:

```
"ng-demo-lib": "git+ssh://git@github.com/nsmolenskii/ng-demo-lib.git",
```

The problem is, when I run npm install on ng-demo-app I get:

```
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/xxx/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/nsmolenskii/ng-demo-lib.git /Users/xxx/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-github-com-nsmolenskii-ng-demo-lib-git-ea5cc26b: Cloning into bare repository '/Users/xxx/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-github-com-nsmolenskii-ng-demo-lib-git-ea5cc26b'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/xxx/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/nsmolenskii/ng-demo-lib.git /Users/xxx/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-github-com-nsmolenskii-ng-demo-lib-git-ea5cc26b: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/xxx/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/nsmolenskii/ng-demo-lib.git /Users/xxx/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-github-com-nsmolenskii-ng-demo-lib-git-ea5cc26b: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/xxx/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/nsmolenskii/ng-demo-lib.git /Users/xxx/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-github-com-nsmolenskii-ng-demo-lib-git-ea5cc26b: 
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/xxx/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/nsmolenskii/ng-demo-lib.git /Users/xxx/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-github-com-nsmolenskii-ng-demo-lib-git-ea5cc26b: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/xxx/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/nsmolenskii/ng-demo-lib.git /Users/xxx/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-github-com-nsmolenskii-ng-demo-lib-git-ea5cc26b: and the repository exists.
npm ERR! Darwin 16.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v7.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --template=/Users/xxx/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/nsmolenskii/ng-demo-lib.git /Users/xxx/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-github-com-nsmolenskii-ng-demo-lib-git-ea5cc26b
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository '/Users/xxx/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-github-com-nsmolenskii-ng-demo-lib-git-ea5cc26b'...
npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/xxx/Desktop/nsmolenskii/ng-demo-app/npm-debug.log
```

I've never tried to import from a remote repository in the package.json. This is new to me. Is there something I need to set up so that Github knows my identity? How do I fix this permissions issue?

Comment: It seems like you tried to access another persons Github repository with your SSH key, which can only work, if your public key was added to their repository (which I doubt).

If you fork the 2 repos to your own account and setup SSH access correctly, this should work without any problems (at least there should not be any Permission Denied errors anymore).

Answer (score 1):

try install form github like this `npm i -D github:user-name/repo-name`, or define like this in your package.json file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "repo-name": "github:user-name/repo-name"
  }
}
```

then run `npm install`

Comment: That doesn't really solve the issue, as I need the library to install from package.json.